# I'm having a problem using struct and scanf in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct student{
    char name[20];
    char lastName[20];
    int number;
};
int main(){
    struct student students[2];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
        printf("%d nci ogrencinin bilgilerini girin:",i+1);
        scanf("%s %s %d",students[i].name,students[i].lastName,&students[i].number);
    }
    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
       printf("%d nci ogrencini bilgileri %s %s %d",students[i].name,students[i].lastName,students[i].number);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

May you recommend a site with c rules?

printf doesn't return student information. What should i change?

Comment: Hint: A string may contain spaces.

Comment: @NihatKerem It seems you mean printf("%d nci ogrencini bilgileri %s %s %d", i+ 1, students[i].name,students[i].lastName,students[i].number);

Comment: Your `printf` statement contains four format specifiers, but you only provided three data arguments.

Comment: thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
 printf("%d nci ogrencini bilgileri %s %s %d",students[i].name,students[i].lastName,students[i].number);
```

Contains 4 Specifiers `%d, %s, %s, %d`

But you only passed 3 parameters.

The first parameter you passed is `students[i].name`, but you try to output this with `%d`.

It looks like you should also be passing Parameter, `i+1`, in the first spot after the format-string:

```
 printf("%d nci ogrencini bilgileri %s %s %d", i+1, students[i].name,students[i].lastName,students[i].number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do steps:

1. Add "&" sign in scanf before first two variables.
2. Add  i+1 in second printf before other variables.

Comment: I solved the problem, but thanks for your help. By the way, you can get information on strings without using '&'